# Finding an applications scalibility point using JMeter

Tags: testing, load, jmeter, scalability

I am trying to find an applications scalibility point using JMeter. I define the scalability point as "The minimum number of concurrent users from which any increase no longer increases the Throughput per second".

I am using the following technique. Schedule my load test to run for an hour, starting a new thread sending SOAP/XML-RPC Requests every 30 seconds. I do this by setting my number of threads to 120 and my ramp up period to 3600 seconds.

Then looking at my TOTAL rows Throughput in my Summary Report Listener. A new row (thread) is added every 30 seconds, the total throughput number rises until it plateaus at about 123 requests per second after 80 of the threads are active in my case. It then slowly drops the throughput number to 120 per second as the last 20 threads are added. I then conclude that my applications scalability point is 123 requests per second with 80 active users.

My question, is this a valid way to find an application scalibility point or is there different technique that I should be trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a technical perspective what you're doing does answer your question regarding one specific user scenario, though I think you might be missing the big picture.

First of all keep in mind that the actual HTTP request you're sending and ramp up times can often impact what you call a scalability point. Are your requests hitting a cache? Are they not random enough? Are they too random? Do they represent real world requests? is 30 seconds going to give you the same results as 20 seconds or 10 seconds?

From my personal experience it's MUCH easier and more intuitive to look at graphs when trying to analyze app performance. It's not just a question of raw numbers but also looking and trends and rates of change.

For example here is an example testing the ghost.org blogging platofom using JMeter with an interactive JMeter results graph.
http://blazemeter.com/blog/ghost-performance-benchmark

Comment: I have performed other load tests, which reflect the real world usage of the API and other heavy load testing covering all the request types that I have.
The API that I am testing has 8 different types of requests and responses.
For this test, I picked the one request that consistently returns the largest size XML response data.

I am saving the results to a CSV JTL file that I have applied graphs to the JTL file like the Response Time Graph.
I agree that I am using the ramp up period in an unconventional manner to add user as the test runs.

Comment: To answer some of your questions:
My requests are not hitting a cache.
For this type of test, I don’t think I need random requests as I am just trying to identify what is the maximum throughput my servers can produce as user are added slowly.

Changing the ramp up period so that new users are added every 10 or 20 seconds shouldn’t affect the results other than I reach the maximum throughput quicker in my results (I should probably test this though to confirm).

Anybody else have any thoughts on this technique of finding the scalability point?

Comment: I'd also make sure to use some application performance monitoring solution like New Relic. While JMeter will provide end-to-end load and response times, it's extremely valuable to see back end performance KPIs.

Comment: I ended up using SOAPUI for the performance monitoring and found the load test graphs and export of data quite useful. Thanks for the advice.